# Сервер cpp. Клиент не может подключиться к серверу

Tags: c++, visual-c++, сеть

Я хочу, чтобы другие люди в разных локальных сетях могли подключаться на мой сервер. То есть я сперва должен зайти в роутер, создать виртуальный сервер с IP адресом моего компьютера в DHCP (192.168.1.101), с портом 1111, с протоколами TCP и UDP. Потом я на стороне сервера (Server.cpp) должен в inet_addr() задать параметр 127.0.0.1 и порт 1111, на стороне клиента я в inet_addr() должен указать белый IP адрес (тот, который можно узнать в https://2ip.ru/) и порт 1111. В итоге запускаю сервер и запускается он нормально, но запускаю клиента и через секунд 10 говорит что не может подключиться к серверу. Не могу понять что я неправильно делаю...

Server.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <string>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#pragma warning (disable: 4996)
using namespace std;
SOCKET users[10];
string users_name[10];
int user_num = 0;
void Users_Msgs(int index) 
{
    char msg1[256];
    while (true)
    {
        recv(users[index], msg1, sizeof(msg1), 0);
        for (int j = 0; j < user_num; j++)
        {
            if (j == index) continue;
            send(users[j], users_name[index].c_str(), users_name[index].length() + 1, 0);
            Sleep(250);
            send(users[j], msg1, sizeof(msg1), 0);
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    WSAData wsaData;
    WORD dll_ver = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
    if (WSAStartup(dll_ver, &wsaData) != 0)
    {
        cout << "Error\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    SOCKADDR_IN addr;
    int size_of_addr = sizeof(addr);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    addr.sin_port = htons(1111);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    SOCKET Listen = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bind(Listen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    listen(Listen, SOMAXCONN);
    SOCKET newConnection;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        newConnection = accept(Listen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &size_of_addr);
        if (newConnection == 0) cout << "Error connecting to client\n";
        else
        {
            cout << "Connection to client " << i << " succesfully\n";
            users[i] = newConnection;
            user_num++;
            char his_name[256];
            recv(newConnection, his_name, sizeof(his_name), 0);
            users_name[i] = his_name;
            cout << "His name is " << his_name << "\n";
            CreateThread(0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)Users_Msgs, (LPVOID)(i), 0, 0);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Client.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#pragma warning (disable: 4996)
using namespace std;
SOCKET Connection;
void Msg_Rec()
{
    char msg[256], name[256];
    while(true)
    {
        recv(Connection, name, sizeof(name), 0);
        recv(Connection, msg, sizeof(msg), 0);
        cout << "\n" <<  name << ": " << msg << "\n";
    }
}
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    
    WSAData wsaData;
    WORD dll_ver = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
    if (WSAStartup(dll_ver, &wsaData) != 0)
    {
        cout << "Error\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    SOCKADDR_IN addr;
    int size_of_addr = sizeof(addr);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    addr.sin_port = htons(1111);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    Connection = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (connect(Connection, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0)
    {
        cout << "Error connecting to server\n";
        system("pause");
    }
    cout << "Connection to server succesfully\n";
    cout << "Enter your name: ";
    char your_name[256];
    cin >> your_name;
    send(Connection, your_name, sizeof(your_name), 0);
    CreateThread(0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)Msg_Rec, 0, 0, 0);
    while(true)
    {
        char msg[256];
        cout << "Enter your message: ";
        cin.getline(msg, sizeof(msg)) >> msg;
        send(Connection, msg, sizeof(msg), 0);
        Sleep(100);
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Настроил виртуальный сервер на роутере:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfR21.jpg

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfR21.jpg]

---

Вопрос решен (в комментариях)!

Comment: Адрес 127.0.0.1 используется только в пределах локальной машины. Если вы понимаете на нем сервер то извне к нему подключиться нельзя. Надо делать bind на 0.0.0.0 что бы ожидать соединения на всех ip которые есть на машине или указать явно тот ip на который реально придут обращения снаружи. В вашем случае видимо 192.168.1.101

Comment: То есть на стороне сервера inet_addr(192.168.1.101), а на клиенте inet_addr(белый ip) ?

Comment: Да, так. Хотя на сервере чаще все таки ставят 0.0.0.0 что бы не задумавыться какой ip стоит

Comment: Все ровно не работает https://imgur.com/a/y0wO88L

Comment: Тут уже сложно сказать почему. Может роутер все таки не пропускает, может еще раньше, провайдер. Может брандмауер windows блочит (хотя он при запуске сервера должен был спросить разрешить ему использовать порт или нет и если сказать что можно дальше он сам все должен пропускать).

Comment: В "Мониторе Ресурсов" посмотрел в портах прослушивания, там есть подключение моего сервера и с портом, который я указал. И брандмауер состояние "Разрешен, не ограничен". То есть проблема или в роутере, или в провайдере. Как Вы думаете, что именно за проблема в них может быть?

Comment: ip явно провайдером заявлен как статический ip или что то в этом роде (часто это дополнительная услуга) ? Можно позвонить в техподдержку и уточнить открыты ли входящие порты снаружи. Если они говорят что все должно быть ok, то разбираться с роутером. Для начала я бы подключил комп на прямую без роутера (если это возможно)

Comment: То есть если я подключу напрямую кабель к компьютеру и у меня по прежнему ничего не будет работать, то придется заказывать статический IP у провайдера?

Comment: Кстати, а где (на какой машине относительно сервера) у вас клиент находится ? Пробовали ли вы его работоспособность в пределах одной машины, т.е. подключаться прямо на 127.0.0.1

Comment: я на своем компьютере запускаю и клиента и сервер

Comment: А, ну тогда все просто :) коннектитесь по 127.0.0.1 (или по 192.168). по реальнику вы его никогда не увидите с той же машины, потому что запрос уходит "в интернет" т.е. на роутер, а тот пакет обратно на вашу машину уже не отдаст. роутер нормально пропустит пакет только если он придет на него через wan-порт и будет уходить в lan. Вот если бы машина была подключена все таки напрямую и реальник был бы прямо на ее сетевой плате то оно бы работало

Comment: То есть если бы допустим я позвал человека, и попросил бы его запустить Client.exe на его собственном компьютере и чтобы он указал мой белый ip, то он благополучно подключится к серверу, а в моем случае нужно подключаться с помощью клиента по 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Да. На реальник получится только откуда то снаружи (при наличии роутера). В пределах машины вы можете соединятся только с адресами, которые подняты на самой машине на любом интерфейсе.

Comment: Короткое дополнение к вашей искромётной дискусии (вот сейчас даже не ирония была). Механизм, который позволяет из локальной сети обратиться по публичному адресу к серверу, находящемуся в той же сети, называется  hairpin nat. Кстати, у меня - удивительным образом! - та же модель роутера, что и на картинке, и он как то сам умеет хаирпинить мои запросы. То есть яя на компе могу запустить сервер (прибиндив его к 0.0.0.0), пробросить порт наружу и со своего компа зайти на этот сервер клиентом. Причем, я для этого ничего не делал.